# Getting the number of rows PER PAGE in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I stated the question above the way I did, because I can already do the following, and it doesn't give me the solution I need.

I can:

- Get the number of pages per sheet
- Get the last USED row on any given SHEET (not per printed page, so that doesn't help)
- I can find out if manual or automatic page breaks have been inserted
  (just not WHERE)

And that's what I need: To know the number of the row for each page break on any given sheet.  Some sheets have 1 page, some have 100.

I need to do this because I need to put something at the bottom of each page, however, the number of pages per sheet is not static.  Some sheets have been set to landscape, others to portrait.  Some sheets have the "Put all columns on one page" option set, which CHANGES the number of rows on that page.

PLEASE NOTE: The solution to this problem is not "Use the footer", as the footer will not accept the data that I need to put on each page.

I also cannot statically decide the number of rows each page type might have --  I let Excel decide that when I set the orientation.

I've been looking for several days now, and I have been unable to find how to determine what the last row on a printed page will be.

I'm using office and VS 2010 and I'm using the office interop. I'm not posting much code because I have no idea what to use at this point.  However, it is safe to say that to access any given worksheet I'm using the following code:

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
```

Excel.Worksheet workSheet;

I'd be willing to bet that there's a very simple way to do this, and I just haven't hit across the right combination of google search terms.  But it's been a few days now, so I thought I'd post something here.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you're setting pagebreaks can you use the HPagebreaks Collection? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174230(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately not.  It doesn't seem to contain the information I need.

Comment: This works ok for me when tested in VBA `Dim pb As HPageBreak: For Each pb In Sheet1.HPageBreaks: Debug.Print pb.Location.Address: Next pb`

Comment: Interesting.  That almost works.  Here's the code I used:
 workSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;
                            
                            foreach (Excel.HPageBreak pb in workSheet.HPageBreaks)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Sheet {0} Page location is {1}",  workSheet.Name, pb.Location.Address);
                            }
-- It only gave me the information for SOME of the pages, not all of them.  Not sure why yet, but it's a start.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a way to calculate that on your own... It is very complicated, because the number of rows on each page depends on many variables (Printer page size, orientation, zoom level, etc.).

You can try to use this: [Repeat specific rows or columns on every printed page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/repeat-specific-rows-or-columns-on-every-printed-page-HA010342842.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  That's a thought, but it won't work for this situation because I'm not actually repeating a set of sells, but adding a shape to each sheet.  Also, I'm asking for the information AFTER the PageBreak has already been inserted.  I can understand MS not providing a way to ask before hand, specifically because of the reasons that you stated.  But after a PageBreak has been set, I can see NO reason why I shouldn't be able to get its position.